# Elegant way of padding footer notes on a single line

Tags: html, css

I want to have contact details(company name, address, email, phone) centered and padded from each other on a single footer line that will get wrapped on a small display.
Right now I have a table with 4 single row columns for the task and this is not very elegant. Plus its different on some browsers.

What would be an elegant and simple way to present this information as a site footer?

Comment: Ok, how about the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/3aqG6/)**</kbd> elegant & simple.

```
<footer>
  <span>Company Name</span>
  <span>Company Address</span>
  <span><a href="mailto:example@example.com">office@example.com</a></span>
  <span>+1 (111) 1111-111</span>
</footer>


footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #555555;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff;
}
footer span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 230px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
footer span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #02b9fc;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
footer span a:hover {
  color: #999;
}
```